# Pandas: splitting a string and returning multiple elements does not work - only one element is returned

Tags: pandas, string, split, return, extract

A dataframe I am working on contains an address line, from which I wish to extract the different variables (street name, number, postal code and country). The address line is filled according to the following template: **"street number, postal code city, country"**.

Using .str.split(), I can get invividual elements from the string. Returning multiple elements however does not work.

So, extracting the country is easy enough. But when I try to get the street and number I run into some troubles. The street can contain one or more whitespaces, but after the last whitespace there is always the number. So I try to do this:

```
df["street_and_number"]=df["address"].str.split(",").str[0]
```

which creates a column with the street *and* the number. So far so good.

If I want to get the street, splitting on whitespaces and extracting everything but the last element seems (to me) a pretty straightforward option:

```
df["street"]=df["street_and_number"].str.split().str[:-1]
```

But this returns a list, see example below:

```
1541    [Burgemeester, Roelenweg]
Name: straat_en_nr, dtype: object
```

I would like to get a string, instead of a list with all the elements. Using the expand option doesn't produce the required result either:

```
df["street"]=df["street_and_number"].str.split(expand=True)[:-1]
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`Series.str.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html):

```
df["street"] = df["street_and_number"].str.split().str[:-1].str.join(' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to extract the beginning of the string up to the first comma, **except the last word**, I believe a one step regex would be appropriate:

```
df['street'] = df['address'].str.extract(r'^([^,]+)\s+\S+,')
```

Example:

```
                                         address       street
0  street name number, postal code city, country  street name
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BdqOjz/1)

Or you can match on digits:

```
df['street'] = df['address'].str.extract(r'^([^,\d]+)(?:\s+\d+)?,')
```

Example:

```
                                       address            street
0   street name 123, postal code city, country       street name 
1  street name only, postal code city, country  street name only
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X8NDqi/1)

Comment: thanks a bunch! Not only does your post provide a useful peek into the world of regex, but the demo you provided is a useful bonus as well. For now I have chosen jezrael's answer as the solution, but I want to give you my thumbs-up as well. :)

Comment: @broekeman no worries, just be careful with chaining `str` commands in pandas. From experience, with 3 or more `str` this is starting to get slower than a python loop.